# How to get select list data from view to controller action without data binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I need to get a string or check box value that are not tied to a model from view, I just add it as a parameter to POST method action in my controller which has the same name and id html attributes in view's form section.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="customValue" id="customValue">
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Title,Content")] Post post, string customValue)
{
.....
}
```

It works fine.

Recently I wanted to try same thing with select list...But I can't figure out how to get that to controller action. All the examples about passing select list data to controller requires strongly typed objects. I want to create my select list with javascript on client side.

Lets say I have this select list in my form html:

```
<select multiple name="myCustomSelectedCars" id="myCustomSelectedCars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

and I will play with options dynamically client side with javascript.
Then how I can get that to my controller?

I can't do something like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Title,Content")] Post post, SelectList myCustomSelectedCars)
{
```

PS:
What I want to get to my action is key/value pair, without model binding. Select list seemed trivial but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried an array of strings `string[]`?

Comment: That works for just getting values of select list, I want to get key/value (key being text part of option tags) pair to my controller action.

Comment: That will not work as the text part is not sent to the server at all

Comment: Once again Scott Hanselman comes to rescue: [ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)... I guess I'll try this.

Comment: Why would want to do this. You seem to be trying to replicate WebForms ViewState. Very anti-MVC!

Comment: I totally agree that it's anti-MVC. However I'm doing some ajax calls and update that part of the form on the fly. Whole form could have been made with ajax calls in mind and probably will be made that way later. For now client wants to see some working UI, that's what I'm going to give. (I didn't share whole code in above question, just the part that tells my problem)

Comment: Then you would need javascript/jquery to get the `.text()` of the selected options and post back that along with the selected `.val()` in your ajax call - but the parameters should be something like `ActionResult Create(..., string[] values, []string texts)` rather that `SelectList`